# AWS Data Pipeline EmrClusterForLoad Error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-data-pipeline

I'm try to transfer data between s3 and dynamodb with AWSDataPipeline.

error message below...

```
Unable to create resource for @EmrClusterForLoad_2017-05-15T18:51:19 
due to: The supplied ami version is invalid. (Service: 
AmazonElasticMapReduce; Status Code: 400; Error Code: 
ValidationException; Request ID: 7ebf0367-399f-11e7-b1d7-29efc4730e41)
```

but, i cannot solve the problem.

help me

[aws datapipeline error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qaGTj.png)

Comment: amiVersion is 3.9.0. is it wrong?

Comment: I have the exact same problem. So you have any news about that ?

Comment: Same here. If you ever find out make sure to tell us

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ami 3.9.0 is not supported in all regions.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-release-3x.html

Also make sure to select a supported EC2 instance type
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-emr-supported-instance-types.html

Finally you need to set "Resize Cluster Before Running" as false in the Table Load activity.

I made it run after doing all these changes. Hopefully it will help you too.

Comment: Please see [How to write an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and edit